# How to pass variable name to Azure stage and job?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am a newbie to azure DevOps and trying to design a pipeline, where I need to pass variable name Green to stage name and job name

**Azure CLI:**

```
echo 'PIPELINES RUNNING'
az pipelines run --name SampleTest --variables  "Variable=Green"
```

Please find below the YAML file code:

```
variables:
  fullVersion: 'null'
  gitTagDate: 'null'
trigger:
  batch: true
  paths:
    exclude:
      - .azuredevops/pull_request_template.md
      - CHANGELOG.md
      - .gitignore
      - .pre-commit-config.yaml
      - README.md
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: DevOpsEngineering/azure-pipeline_templates
stages:
  - stage: SmokeTest $(Variable)
    jobs:
      - job: SmokeTest $(Variable)
        timeoutInMinutes: 90
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
        continueOnError: true
        steps:
          - task: Gradle@2
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              tasks: clean test
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
          - task: Gradle@2
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              tasks: publishResults
            env:
              SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

**Output**

Stage  SmokeTest $(Variable) has an invalid name. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '*' and may not start with a number.
Stage SmokeTest $(Variable) job  SmokeTest $(Variable) has an invalid name. Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '*' and may not start with a number.

Comment: Can you indicate what is the problem? output/error

Comment: @GeralexGR : Please have a look at the output section above.

Comment: could you try to change the variable name to something like myVar just to verify that this keyword can be used

Comment: I have tried that but getting same issue

Comment: Stage or job names can't include variables; they're evaluated too early, before the variables. You should try using a parameter value instead, but I'm not sure if even that is possible.

Comment: also note: do you really need to customise the stage or job *name*, or is customising the *displayName* what you actually want to do?

Comment: @VinceBowdren: I am trying to use a variable name in the stage and job, I have tried to use displayName with the job and stage but it does not show me the variable value in the stage and job name displayName:$(Variable)